# How to notify developers of external framework constraints?

Tags: c#, .net

We have code that is called by an external framework, [ARDEN](http://www.openclinical.org/gmm_ardensyntax.html).  Short of a comment (easily overlooked), how can I effectively notify developers of tie in's to this framework?  Specifically, a tie in couples the CLASS, NAMESPACE and METHOD to said framework.

```
namespace MyCompany//changing namespace for this class is NOT SAFE
{
public class MyClass//changing class name is NOT SAFE
{
   [TiedToArdenAttribute]//maybe an attribute?
   public void MethodCalledByArden() {}//adding params, changing name is NOT SAFE

   public void NotCalledByArden() {}//changing this method signature, name, params is OK
}
}
```

Under normal circumstances, for example when I change the name of `MyClass` in an assembly via visual studio I can't compile without fixing the references to said class.  If the namespace, classname or method name changes...there should be a warning that says "best fix Arden to deal with this change".  I considered an Error, but since there's no way to verify Arden is fixed I don't believe that will work.

Is there a way to achieve a similar result for this external framework?

Comment: Apart from comments, three possibilities come to mind: implementing a façade pattern, have the class implement an interface (ICallableByArden ?), or adding test cases to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think whatever you do can be undone by other developers - they can rename class, remove comments, remove attributes.

Try to move this class to separate library instead. And in your project add reference to compiled assembly. That will make class name fixed in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If others are using the code, it is best to talk in terms of contracts and not class instances via interfaces. By allowing the consumer to use an Interface will dictate the primary changes such as property changes...but things like internal class name changes will not affect a consumer. Plus you can version your classes, while working on a new class, the old class could still be used by the consumer until the factory internally releases it, without the consumer knowing that V2 of the class is being used.